# How to Save NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

Can anybody say me how to save NSTimer ?
I need to display that, at how much time player completed his/her game. please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you wanna know how much time a user has spent for playing a game?

Comment: yes, and after that i have to display that time in leaderboard.

Comment: i just tested my answered code and it's work perfect, i dont know why some one give minus requtation but angel i just req to you just implement my answer code hope its a help you... thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this way..

`int currentTime;`

`BOOL isGameOver;`

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
    {
       isGameOver=FALSE;
       [self start];
       [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    }

- (IBAction)start{

    currentTime = 0;// SET 60 SECODE AS STATICULLY YOU CAN SET YOUR OWN TIME
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    //creates and fires timer every second
    myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];
}

-(IBAction)gameOverAction
{
    isGameOver=TRUE;

//your game action Whenever its game over this method fire and Set One Bool value in this method like
}

-(void)showTime{



        if(isGameOver==TRUE)
        {

            [myTimer invalidate];
            myTimer = nil;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Rount Time is %.2d", currentTime]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

        //you can save this [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Rount Time is %.2d", currentTime] in nsuserdefoult or database like bellow

          NSString *myGameLastTime =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Rount Time is %.2d", currentTime] ;
          NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          [defaults setObject:myGameLastTime forKey:@"gameoverTime"];

          [defaults synchronize];

         //now you can get this time anyplace in your project like [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"gameoverTime"]


        }

        currentTime++;
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d", currentTime];

    NSLog(@"my lable == %@",lbl.text);


}
```

Hope its help you  all the best

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `NSTimer`. I suggest you using `NSDate`

When the game starts:

```
startDate = [NSDate date];
```

when the game is over:

```
endDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
```

so now you have time spent and can use it however you like. You can save it in `NSUserDefaults` just like ordinary `double` value

Answer (score 0):

U should do some research before ask such questions,  its easy to figure it out with google, it will take something like 20 min  max,

```
NSUserDefaults *YourTimerName=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaultsPassword setObject:YourTimerName forKey:@"key1"];
[defaultsPassword synchronize];
```

and then u can recover it like that

```
Nsstring *str=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key1"];
```

but you need to make your timer  Nsstring format firstly and then save it

Answer (score -1):

`NSTimer` is just a source of periodic time events, there’s not much to save. If you use it to keep track of time in your game, there has to be a variable that keeps the total time. Save that into `NSUserDefaults` or somewhere.

Comment: okay, but i m new in ios so can u say me how to save? i m trying to save time in NSUserDeafults but gives "0" in output.